# npm install express will cause many package to be installed

Tags: npm, installation, publish, npm-install

I am reading the [Installing npm packages locally](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally) guide and looking for information about why when I use `npm install express` to install that package, nearly 40 other packages installed in the *node_modules* sub-directory.

Also if NPM supports the method as described above, how do we use `npm publish` to publish a bundle of packages in one command for download in NPM?

Comment: As of v3, NPM  flattens dependencies. So those other packages that you see in `node_modules` are `express` dependencies.

Comment: by the way i have another question to ask ,if i develop a project named "a" with a dependency named "b",the one "b" is also developed by me. and the "a" and "b" are under coding the same time. how do i share my project with other cowokers with the npm.   it looks like i need to publish "a" and "b" to npm all the time ,or i have to use git to manage the code untill all done and publish in the npm?